# Transferring Data from User Form to Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform, to input employee name, with checkboxes for trainings.
[image: User Form]

When a user inputs an employee name that value should be populated in L which is merged with M.
For any checkboxes that are checked I would like to return "x" into the appropriate columns for those trainings.

Note that there is another data set one row below this one with same headings but for Journeymen not Foreman (this is why my code below refers to AZ2 which captures last row of the upper data set and I plan to do the same for the bottom data set).

Data Set Example:
[image: Data Set Example]

My code is not working even for just the employee name.

```vb
Private Sub Submit_Click()
    Set act = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    bot_row = act.Range("AZ2")
    act.Range("L" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
    act.Range("L" & bot_row & ":M" & bot_row).Value = EmpNameTextBox.Text
End Sub
```

Edit: Working code

```vb
Private Sub Submit_Click()
    Dim act As Worksheet
    Set act = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    bot_row = act.Range("AZ2")
    
    act.Range("L" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
    act.Range("L9:AB9").Copy
    act.Range("L" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    act.Range("L" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    Range("P" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).ClearContents
    Range("L" & bot_row) = EmpName.Value
    Range("P" & bot_row) = EmpPhone.ValueDim cBox As Control
    For Each cBox In Me.Controls
      If TypeOf cBox Is msforms.CheckBox Then
         'potential test msgbox
         'MsgBox "Box " & cBox.Caption & " has a click value = " & cBox.Value
            If cBox.Value Then
            If cBox.Caption = "Competent" Then
                Range("Q" & bot_row).Value = "x"
            ElseIf cBox.Caption = "OSHA 30hr" Then
                Range("R" & bot_row).Value = "x"
            ElseIf cBox.Caption = "OSHA 10hr" Then
                Range("S" & bot_row).Value = "x"
            ElseIf cBox.Caption = "CPR" Then
               Range("T" & bot_row).Value = "x"
            ElseIf cBox.Caption = "Hand Signal" Then
               Range("U" & bot_row).Value = "x"
            ElseIf cBox.Caption = "Rigging" Then
               Range("V" & bot_row).Value = "x"
            ElseIf cBox.Caption = "Asbestos" Then
               Range("W" & bot_row).Value = "x"
            ElseIf cBox.Caption = "Certa Torch" Then
               Range("X" & bot_row).Value = "x"
            ElseIf cBox.Caption = "Scaffold" Then
               Range("Y" & bot_row).Value = "x"
            ElseIf cBox.Caption = "Fork/Lull" Then
               Range("Z" & bot_row).Value = "x"
            ElseIf cBox.Caption = "Manlift" Then
               Range("AA" & bot_row).Value = "x"
            ElseIf cBox.Caption = "ATV" Then
               Range("AB" & bot_row).Value = "x"
            End If
         End If
           
      End If
    Next

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: You would likely benefit from using an actual Microsoft Form and then pushing that data into a table that would update your spreadsheet. It looks like you've already invested a lot on the current process, but Excel's VBA forms have limitations and are far harder to develop than simple web forms. Good luck.

Comment: Noted.  However I am making progress.  I just need help to figure out how to generate "x" in the applicable cells if the userform checkbox's are checked if they are not the other applicable cells should be blank.  Updated code in original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably work. I would recommend you include this in your code at end. I would also suggest using something more dynamic with columns. Naming them would be easy and ensures you could make easy updates without too much modification of VBA code.

```
 Dim cBox As Control
    For Each cBox In Me.Controls
      If TypeOf cBox Is msforms.CheckBox Then
         'potential test msgbox
         'MsgBox "Box " & cBox.Caption & " has a click value = " & cBox.Value
         If cBox.Value Then
            If cBox.Caption = "CPR" Then
               Range("T" & bot_row).Value = "X"
            ElseIf cBox.Caption = "Hand Signal" Then
               Range("U" & bot_row).Value = "X"
      
            'etc.
            End If
         End If
           
      End If
    Next
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond earlier.  It works like a charm.  I will definitely clean up the naming as you suggested.  Thanks, updated code in original post under EDIT.

Comment: So quick question, I added a checkbox for Chicago Resident & Apprentice.  I tried to add the following code to apply conditional formatting, however it isn't working curious if you can help me out with this as well?  Here is the current code I have been trying:

`ElseIf cBox.Caption = "Chicago Resident" Then
Range("L" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
ElseIf cBox.Caption = "Apprentice" Then
Range("L" & bot_row).FormatConditions(1).Font.Color = vbRed`